# set a local variable as selected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set a local variable as selected in a dropdownlist but it is not working for me.

Here my code :

```html
@{
List
<SelectListItem>
dateEcheancier = new List
<SelectListItem>
();
foreach (var dateEch in arrayDateEcheancier)
{
dateEcheancier.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = dateEch, Value = dateEch });
}
<div id="md-select-forcage" class="md-select px-0" style="min-width:0px">
   @Html.DropDownList("DateEche", new SelectList(dateEcheancier, "Value", "Text", (Selected .ToString())), new { @class = "form-conrol" })
</div>
}
```

And selected value it is a local variable in my code :

```html
 string Selected = ech.Value[i];
 Selected = arrayMontantsIds[0];
```

Note that when i add a selected value like this "20/01/2019" a date in my select list it is working so how i solve this problem

Comment: Is that `arrayMontantsIds` array of `DateTime`? Try `String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", arrayMontantsIds[0])` if the array is `DateTime[]`, otherwise you need to convert it manually and specify the format string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it is an array of string [] not datetime but it contain date in format string like "20/20/2019" so what i do ?

Comment: @mecabmecaba what is your actual value for selected? as you have given  string Selected = ech.Value[i];
 Selected = arrayMontantsIds[0]; whats 'i' ?

Comment: @Anoos it is a dictionnary and i do a loop for all the dictionnary values ( for (int i = 0; i < ech.Value.Count; i++) )

Comment: ech.Value[i] it is the selected value

Comment: @mecabmecaba and you are setting the value two times, you'll always have arrayMontantsIds[0] value in your Variable 'Selected'

Comment: yes exactly always

Comment: @mecabmecaba are you setting your variable at controller?

Comment: @Anoos yes the dictionnary is in controller and the variable too

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag

in your controller, set the value as below

```
ViewBag.Selected=arrayMontantsIds[0];
```

in your view

```
<div id="md-select-forcage" class="md-select px-0" style="min-width:0px">
   @Html.DropDownList("DateEche", new SelectList(dateEcheancier, "Value", "Text",ViewBag.Selected) , new { @class = "form-conrol" })
</div>
```

Comment: but i have a foreach in my view so it is not static arrayMontantsIds[0] and it is declared in view not in controller in controller just i have the dictionnary with data

Comment: i have the dictionnary in a repository this is the method ( public static Dictionary<Text, List<string>>[] ) i can't declare viewbag i want a solution in my view without controller because i have the selected value in my view

Comment: So what you actually need in your Selected? whats the relation between your dictionary and arrayMontantsIds[0] ?? please elaborate your question! @mecabmecaba

Comment: string[] arrayMontantsIds = ValuesLine.Split(';');
                                        int CountTab = arrayMontantsIds.Count();
                                        ValuesLine = arrayMontantsIds[0];
                                        IdValueLine = arrayMontantsIds[1];